# How to replace null in all type of number column with -in power query

Tags: excel-2010, powerquery

I have 5 columns in power query with number type and there are null in some cells. I want to replace all those null with-. But power query did allow as - is not a value. I also have mixed number and text in last 3 columns, I want to clear all those text or number to leave it blank. I did not see such option in power query but only manually do it in excel.

Comment: There is no reason to replace a null with a dash thst I can think of. Replace it with zero and format zero in excel to display as dash. For the remaking columns transform them to each null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear why you would want to replace nulls with hyphens, but you can do both of your actions using the `Table.ReplaceValue` function. However, you will need to do this in the Advanced Editor.

Read MS HELP for the `Table.ReplaceValue` function to better understand the arguments. Also there are numerous online blogs about using the `each` statement as well as using the function in this manner.

*Note that the `Table.ReplaceValue` function will change the column datatype to `any`. This is especially important when replacing the null with a hyphen as the hyphen is **not** a number*

For example, given this table:
[image]

***M Code***

```
let

//Get data from an Excel Table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"2", Int64.Type}, {"abc", type text}}),

//Rename columns
    #"Rename Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"2", "col1"}, {"abc", "col2"}}),

    #"Replace Col2 with blank" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Rename Columns",
        each [col2],
        "",
        Replacer.ReplaceValue,
        {"col2"}),

    #"Replace Col1 nulls with hyphen" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Replace Col2 with blank",
        null,
        "-",
        Replacer.ReplaceValue,
        {"col1"}
    )
in
    #"Replace Col1 nulls with hyphen"
```

***Results***
[image]

If you have multiple columns to "Blank" or "hyphen" you can do it with this type of code:

```
...
  #"Replace number cols nulls with hyphen" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Changed Type",
        null,
        "-",
        Replacer.ReplaceValue,
        {"col1","col4"}),

    #"Blank Columns" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Replace number cols nulls with hyphen",
        List.Combine(Table.ToColumns(Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"col2","col3"}))),
        "",
        (x,y,z)=>if List.Contains(y,x) then z else x,
        {"col2","col3"})
...
```

***Note:** If you want to replace nulls with hyphens using the UI, you will need to first change the datatype of that column to `type text`. But I don't know how to blank the mixed columns without using the `Advanced Editor`.*

Instead of using `Table.ReplaceValue` to change the `type any` columns to *null*, you can also use `Table.TransformColumns`.

The code below will work on all columns with `type number` and/or `type any` and do the changes you requested without having to hard code the column names:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"col1", Int64.Type}, {"col2", type any}, {"col3", Int64.Type}, {"col4", type any}}),

//Select typed columns this way as `Table.ColumnsOfType` returns all the columns when looking for `type any`
    schema = Table.SelectColumns(Table.Schema(#"Changed Type"),{"Name","Kind"}),
    #"Number Cols" = Table.SelectRows(schema, each [Kind] = "number")[Name],
    #"Any Cols" = Table.SelectRows(schema, each [Kind] = "any")[Name],

//Blank "any" columns
    #"Blank Any" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", List.Transform(#"Any Cols",(li)=> {li, each null})),

//Replace nulls with hyphens in Number columns
    #"Replace Nulls" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Blank Any",
        null,
        "-",
        Replacer.ReplaceValue,
        #"Number Cols"),

//Optionallly change number columns to type text
    #"NumberCols to Text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replace Nulls", List.Transform(#"Number Cols", each {_, type text}))
in
    #"NumberCols to Text"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**
-> I think there is no direct way to replace nulls with "-" in Power Query, but you can use a workaround.

**Select the column with the nulls.**

1. Click Transform > Replace Values.
2. In the Replace values dialog box, enter the following:
3. Value to find:null
4. Value to replace with:""

Then Click OK to Close the Power Query Editor.
This will replace all of the nulls in the column with empty strings.

I think this will help you. Thanks

Comment: *"I think there is no direct way to replace nulls with "-" in Power Query"*. I'm not sure what you mean by this, since it clearly **is possible** to do this in PQ. Please explain.